# Fetched Data doesn't get showed in the widget

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I have a created a function named fetchData() which first fetches images from the cloud storage and then details regarding to that image gets fetched from cloud firestore and all the data gets stored as List<Map<String, dynamic>> format but there is a problem that the data is not been displaying in the widget after getting fetched. After debugging, I found out that the elements inside the list gets change after some time and list elements gets deleted

So can anyone help me with this issue Please!!

**fetchData()**

```
Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> fetchData(String occasion) async {
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> files = [];
  final ImageDetails imageDetails = ImageDetails(occasion: occasion);
  final Future<ListResult> result =  reference.ref().child(occasion).list(); //reference.ref(occasion+'/').list(), reference.ref().child(occasion).list();
  result.then((value) async {
    final List<Reference> allFiles = value.items;
    await Future.forEach<Reference>(allFiles, (file) async {
      final String imageUrl = await file.getDownloadURL();
      debugPrint(imageUrl);
      List<String> urlSplit = imageUrl.split('/');
      String docID = urlSplit.join();
      debugPrint(docID);
      final ImageDataInfo data = await info(docID);
      files.add({
        'url': imageUrl,
        'description': data.description,
        'price': data.price
      });
    });
  });
  return files;
}
```

**info()**

```
Future<ImageDataInfo> info(String docID){
  final CollectionReference<Map<String,dynamic>> imageCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(occasion);
  final DocumentReference<Map<String, dynamic>> imgDocument = imageCollection.doc(docID);
  return imgDocument.get().then((value){
    return ImageDataInfo(
        description: value.get('description'),
        price: value.get('price')
    );
  });
}
```

**fetchData() passed as future in FutureBuilder**

```
FutureBuilder(
            future: fetchData(occasion),//('Wedding'), (occasion),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Map<String,dynamic>>> snapshot){
              debugPrint(snapshot.data.toString());
              debugPrint(snapshot.data?.length.toString());
              final imgData = snapshot.data;
              if (snapshot.hasData){
                return Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:300.h),
                  child: Text(imgData![0]['description']),
                );
              } else {
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
              }

            }
        )
```

[Issue Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CX441.png)

[File where method is been built](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aom1F.png)

[Data Retrieval class - 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEDEQ.png)

[Data Retrieval class - 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PX1ea.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should refactor the **fetchData** method so that it truly returns a **Future** that wraps your **List<Map<String, dynamic>>** because your issue here is that you're returning the list without awaiting appropriately when you're fetching the values. Refactor it as such:

```dart
Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> fetchData(String occasion) async {

  // create a Completer, type List<Map<String, dynamic>>;
  // I'd advice to actually map it to a Dart model in the future
  // for now this is good
  Completer<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> listCompleter = Completer();

  List<Map<String, dynamic>> files = [];
  final ImageDetails imageDetails = ImageDetails(occasion: occasion);
  final Future<ListResult> result =  reference.ref().child(occasion).list(); 
  
  // you're hooking a callback to the result as opposed to "awaiting" on it
  // which will execute it asynchronously, and skip right to the last line
  // so you can keep it like this for now, but see the other changes below
  result.then((value) async {
    final List<Reference> allFiles = value.items;

    await Future.forEach<Reference>(allFiles, (file) async {
      final String imageUrl = await file.getDownloadURL();
      debugPrint(imageUrl);
      List<String> urlSplit = imageUrl.split('/');
      String docID = urlSplit.join();
      debugPrint(docID);
      final ImageDataInfo data = await info(docID);

      files.add({
        'url': imageUrl,
        'description': data.description,
        'price': data.price
      });

      // here, complete the Completer by passing the populated list
      listCompleter.complete(files);
    });
  });

  // return a future out of the completer
  // instead of an empty list
  return listCompleter.future;
}
```

By creating an instance of **Completer** and returning a **Future** out of the **Completer**'s instance, you're handing off an object to your **FutureBuilder** that it can truly wait on, while the data inside gets processed asynchronously; then you notified whoever subscribed to that returned future (i.e. the FutureBuilder) by saying **Completer.complete**, passing the processed value through.

Comment: I tried your code sir but it only fetches the initial data

Comment: Your issue was that it wasn't fetching data, so that's what it does. Are you seeing the data on the widget now? If you have a follow-up question, then I believe it should be addressed on a separate issue. Let me know so we can mark this as correct or I can help you with another issue, but on a separate question. Thank you for understanding.

Comment: Yes sir this code is correct but it fetches only 1 data everytime so now i want to ask you is how can i fetch all the data from firebase and display to screen when every time the widget gets built